# How can I draw on a three.js model?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a three.js model I would like to draw on in a scene, how can I do this? I would like to be able to 'graffiti' on my scene models

Comment: You can try adding a transparent canvas on top and draw into that. Not 100% sure this would actually work in all browsers due to the WebGL interactions, but there's a good chance it will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take look at this example

https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Texture-From-Canvas.html

you use a 2d canvas as a texture for the object on which you want to "paint"

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: texture, side:THREE.DoubleSide } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry(canvas.width, canvas.height),
    material
  );
```

when the canvas is changed you have to set needsUpdate of the texture etc.

take a look at example for RTT(render to texture) http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_rtt.html
there you can see similar process (a 3D scene is used instead of a canvas)

Comment: Got it working perfectly using your method except WebGL crashes after I alter the canvas a load of times. Any ideas?

Comment: your GPU memory might be owerflowing if the texture is not disposed properly, make sure you call `.dispose() `on any texture, material or geometry you are not using(or you dont want to in future)

Comment: Calling `.dispose()` on the old objects has fixed it, thank you very much! :)